# Raycast not activating OnTriggerEnter()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have what I assume is a very trivial problem but I cannot for the life of me figure it out. I am writing a simple fog of war system where the “fog” objects disappear when they enter the line of sight of a unit, represented by a raycast. I have confirmed my line of sight raycasts are hitting the fog colliders. The OnTriggerEnter() function of the fog class runs when it is hit by the unit’s boxcollider, but not it’s raycasts. Here are simple scripts for my fog and unit controllers:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FogTmp : MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("hit by: " + other.name);

    }

}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UnitTmp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float LoS = 12f;
        private void FixedUpdate()
        {

            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(1.5f, 0, 0), transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left), LoS))
            { Debug.Log("hitting!"); }
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + new Vector3(1.5f, 0, 0), transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left) * LoS, Color.green);

        }

    }
```

The unit has a rigidbody component and the fog boxcollider is set to “Is Trigger”, and I’m not messing around with any layers. If anyone has any idea what’s going on here please let me know.

Comment: Why the offset of 1.5f and have you double checked that left is the desired direction? Are the colliders of a type that can be hit by raycasts (e.g., BoxCollider, SphereCollider) and are they big enough?

Comment: raycasts do not trigger trigger events, objects do

Comment: @BugFinder Are you sure about this? Physics.Raycast has a specific queryTriggerInteraction option, from the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html):

“Specifying queryTriggerInteraction allows you to control whether or not Trigger colliders generate a hit”

Comment: @bdbdbd I read that raycasts won't collide if their origin is in another collider, so I added the offset to be safe. The colliders are BoxColliders and I know the direction/size works because the Debug.Log() in UnitTmp tells me it is colliding with the FogTmp objects, but for some reason OnTriggerEnter() is not called

Comment: @KyleDavid yes, a raycast will "hit" a trigger, I believe, but it does not trigger the events, because its not a physical strike.. it is a can you see it

Comment: `queryTriggerInteraction` allows raycasts to ignore (or default hit) colliders marked as triggers.   The easiest way to handle this is to expose a function on FogTmp that you can call when you get a raycast hit.  Your trigger function can also call that same function, eliminating code duplication.

Comment: so why there isn't a queryTriggerInteraction in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as was already stated before: **Raycasts do not cause `OnTriggerEnter`** and the `queryTriggerInteraction` rather means "Should a raycast HIT triggers or not?"

=> You want to have a public method like

```
public void DoYourThing(Component other)
{
   Debug.Log("hit by: " + other.name);
}
```

and then in your raycast check an do

```
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(1.5f, 0, 0), transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left), out var hit, LoS))
{ 
    if(hit.transform.TryGetComponent<FogTmp>(out var fogTmp) 
    { 
        fogTmp.DoYourThing(this);  
    }
}
```

---

Note that for the kind of system you are talking about you might rather want to use a [`Physics.OverlapSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) around your player instead of a single `Raycast`

or as alternative and back to triggers: You could have a custom cone-shaped mesh, use a `MeshCollider` and actually again go back to `OnTriggerEnter` by simply moving such a "line of sight trigger" along with the player

Comment: My solution ended up being very similar to this, thank you!